# Emacs Haskell mode - Speedbar not updating

Tags: macos, haskell, emacs

I am using Emacs 23.4 on OS X (from http://emacsformacosx.com/). My `~/.emacs` file contains:

```lisp
(load "/path/to/haskell-site-file")

(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-doc-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indent)

(require 'speedbar)
(speedbar-add-supported-extension ".hs")

(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/ghc-mod-1.10.15")
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
(autoload 'ghc-init "ghc" nil t)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook (lambda () (ghc-init) (flymake-mode)))
```

When I invoke Speedbar with `M-x speedbar` I do get a speedbar frame which shows Variables, Imports, Instances and Datatypes for the Haskell file. But when I edit the Haskell file, the speedbar frame does not refresh to reflect the edits to the file. I tried invoking the `Speedbar > Update` menu, but that did not do the trick. How do I update the speedbar frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speedbar uses imenu by default to fetch tags from your buffer, and imenu is very lazy about reparsing your buffer.  In addition, once speedbar has a list of tags, it keeps using that list until you 'close' the file.  Next time you open the file like to see the tags, it will refetch tags from imenu (or whichever tool you are using for tags.)

Since imenu is even lazier than speedbar, you can use a speedbar shift-click to re-open a file, and speedbar will force imenu to reparse.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by "speedbar shift-click to re-open a file". Closing the buffer (C-x k) and then re-opening the file refreshes speedbar on my machine, but is there a faster way to force this - say with some elisp?

Comment: In speedbar, if you close a file (ie click the small icon near the file name to collapse the tag list so it is no longer there), then when you press shift and click on the icon to see the tags, it will reparse the buffer.  This would be shift-middle-click with old school emacs keybindings, and I think a double-click will work too.  I forget the different variants.

Comment: shift-click did not work for me. :( I am on OS X, if that matters.

Comment: I found a workaround. If I reload the buffer with `C-x C-v`, speedbar shows the updated list of functions when reopened.